# Start stored procedure in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, gridview

I have a problem with adding column into `GridView`, which will trigger a start of a stored procedure.

I'm trying to make a library application.

I am displaying available books in a `GridView` and I need to add a new column from which it will hold the trigger of a stored procedure and get column `id_book`, as parameter for the stored procedure.

This is the output with my notes. What do I need. Thank you for help.

- Add a new column Lend book.
- In every column have a link that will trigger stored procedure and get `id_book` from current row.

[image]

Part of my gridview markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id_book" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id_book" HeaderText="id_book" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id_book" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="book_name" HeaderText="book_name" SortExpression="book_name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id_author" HeaderText="id_author" SortExpression="id_author" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="state" HeaderText="state" SortExpression="state" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[lendBook_sp]
    @id_reader int,
    @id_book int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.lendBook (id_book, id_reader, lendDate)  
    VALUES (@id_book, @id_reader, GETDATE())

    UPDATE dbo.book
    SET state = 0
    WHERE id_book = @id_book
END
```

Comment: Do you have any code you've tried in calling your Stored Procedure?

Comment: Still no, because i don't know, how i get id_book from current row, which i push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have edited your HTML code to add column to the Grid

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id_book" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnRowCommand="gridView_RowCommand" >
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id_book" HeaderText="id_book" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id_book" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="book_name" HeaderText="book_name" SortExpression="book_name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="id_author" HeaderText="id_author" SortExpression="id_author" />
    <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="state" HeaderText="state" SortExpression="state" />

    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="EditRow" Text="Lend" CausesValidation=false></asp:ButtonField>
</Columns>
```

Below is the C# code for the event which will be called when the user clicks on the "Lend" link.

```
 protected void gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("EditRow"))
    {
        int _bookIDEdit = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString())].Values["id_book"].ToString());

    }
}
```

After getting the BookID to the intege variable, you can call the StoredProcedure.

Comment: Oh, that's it. Thanks a lot.